# Using UK Immigration line with baby who does not yet hold an EU passport

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, uk-citizens

My wife and I are flying back to the UK with our baby. We both hold UK passports, however our baby doesn't hold an EU passport yet. (They have a separate non-EU passport that is valid for entering the UK)

Does anyone know if we can still go through the faster UK/EU immigration line at the airport, or would we have to go through the slower non-EU line?

Comment: Is your baby on any terrorism watch lists or wanted for crimes against humanity?

Comment: Be aware that the EU line is not always faster. It often depends on timing and which flights have arrived recently.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I haven't been through Heathrow that often recently, however the EU line always appeared much quicker. Maybe that changed post-Olympics

Comment: There is always someone directing people in the immigration lines, so I would ask them. Sometimes they have let me and a friend join the EU line even if only one of us has an EU passport. But sometimes they haven't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A comment on [flyertalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/archive/t-1304433.html) addresses this exact issue:

> At LHR, it's been ok about 140 times in the last 24 months for my
>   family doing just as you wish to do. Not one negative comment from any
>   UKBA employee about doing so.
>
> Even non-EU/EFTA/EEC nationals who have infants or toddlers are often
>   directed -- late at night at LHR -- to use the shorter/emptied out EU
>   national line at LHR after that line is cleared but the
>   non-EU/EFTA/EEC line is substantively backed up. See this at LHR T5
>   and T3.